# Shedlock skipped runs

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, shedlock, distributed-lock

I am using **shedlock** to implement a use-case of distributed locking.
My app is running on 20 machines, and I want scheduler to be executed once in every 5 minutes in any 1 machine by using implicit distributed locking provided by shedlock library.

###### Scheduler:

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */5 * * * *")
    @SchedulerLock(name = "executeTaskLock",
            lockAtLeastFor = "1m",
            lockAtMostFor = "4m")
    public void executeTask() throws Exception {
        LockAssert.assertLocked();

        // task executes here which completed in around (400ms - 2s)
    }
```

###### Config:

```
    @Bean
    public JedisPool jedisPoolForSchedulerLocking() {

        JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(2);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(2);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMinIdle(1);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(500);

        return new JedisPool(jedisPoolConfig, {host}, {port}, {timeout}, {port}); 
    }

    @Bean
    public LockProvider lockProvider(@Qualifier("jedisPoolForSchedulerLocking") JedisPool jedisPool) {
        return new JedisLockProvider(jedisPool, "PRD");
    }
```

###### Issue:

I am seeing sometimes scheduler is missing the runs, for instance it runs at 12:25, 12:30 and then runs at 12:45, **missed 2 runs here**. Actual task completes in around (400ms - 3s), thus I have setup `1m` and `4m` as `lockAtLeastFor` and `lockAtMostFor`. config seems correct to me.

Doesn't know what's failing here exactly. As per official docs this can run more than once(which is fine for my use-case) but should never miss the runs.

**pom.xml** :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.42.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>shedlock-provider-redis-jedis</artifactId>
            <version>4.42.0</version>
        </dependency>

<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<spring-boot.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
```

Comment: Is the miss happening very frequently.. or after any deployment or something ?

Comment: @JayYadav, this was happening very frequently, after that I have increased the spring.schedule pool size and now it has come down, even though there are only 2 scheduler running in the service and I have set the pool size to be 5, Still I see, it misses some time, though the miss has been reduced, but it's still there.

Comment: Problem has to be non-availability of threads, tbh never seen Spring scheduler missing run, by default the pool size is 1, can you set these 2 properties and check logs whether threads from scheduler pool are being used or not.
`spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=10
spring.task.scheduling.thread-name-prefix=shedlock-th-`